# Sites where to practice limits and derivations?

Tags: calculus, reference-request

Can you recommend me some sites where I can practice limits and derivations? It will be great if every example has described approach and solution. I found only [Khan Academy](https://www.khanacademy.org) yet. Do you know about some alternatives?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should go to edx . It is a name of a site where you can learn about various sciences.You can chose math section in that & go for some calculus courses. in some you might get what you want. It's absolutely free.